# Fine Uploader - Internet Explorer 8 asks for download the endpoint.php

Tags: internet-explorer-8, fine-uploader

I integrated Fine Uploader into my website and when I try to upload a file with Internet Explorer 8, I get a message that ask me if I want to download the endpoint.php file. With Internet Explorer 9, everything is working fine.

Comment: What is the Content-Type of your response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that uploads are sent in IE9 and older via a form submit targeting a hidden iframe, and the response comes in as the content of the iframe.  Most likely, you are returning a response with a Content-Type of "application/json".  This may prompt the browser to attempt to download the content of the response.  One way to get around this is to ensure the Content-Type of your response is "text/plain".  This is described in the Fine Uploader documentation.